# How do I find the GPU device ID on Apple Silicon?

Tags: docker, macos, gpu, apple, arm64

I use a MacBook Pro and Mac Studio with M1 and M2 chips, respectively. I'm trying to use a terminal command that has this parameter `--device=/dev/****`, which refers to the GPU device ID.

How do I find the GPU device ID?

To me, it seems that in Apple Silicon-based Macs, the integrated GPU doesn't have the same kind of device IDs as discrete GPUs found in more traditional PC setups. Thus, if I'm trying to use a tool or command designed for systems with NVIDIA, AMD, or similar GPUs that expect a device ID, it might not work as intended on my Mac.

Can anybody make any suggestions? Is there any hope of me being successfully able to run a command in terminal that expects a GPU device ID?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick - open a terminal and run `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`

Example output:

```
Graphics/Displays:

    Intel UHD Graphics 630:

      Chipset Model: Intel UHD Graphics 630
      ...
      Device ID: 0x3e9b
      ...
```